# What is the best practices of making a repository class with EF4 code first?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, design-patterns

There seem to be many ways to apply the repository patterns that is why i need your opinion and a good clear answer on what seem the best way of applying the repository pattern. It is the generic repository ? But there is a problem where some domain object dont have the same behaviour as others. It is specify repository ? What about code repeatition between repositories? it is both combinaison ? how about using a di container for both kind of implementation ?

Thanks

Edit: the orm i am using is entity framework 4. Would be nice to have an example with EF4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post by Gabriel Schenker](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) is a good explanation of the repository pattern. He implements it with NHibernate (you don't say which ORM you are using) and provides a generic base repository. For me the repository pattern is very connected to testing and being able to fake it or mock it and this blog post also shows how to make your own fake.

In my experience most repositories share some common functionality e.g. GetById, Add, Remove. So it is useful to have a base class that can be inherited. Where it can get a little trickier is when you start thinking about dynamic Linq queries and how those can be tested.

Examples of repository patterns with Linq can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090215004055/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/26/linq-to-nhibernate.aspx) and [here](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/) but I would start simple as these could be overkill for some projects.

Comment: Nice explanation, do you have any examples of when dynamic linq queries would be used?

Comment: I added two links which show how to use Linq with NHibernate.

Comment: Sorry i just realized i didnt said the orm i was using which is entity framework 4. Do you have some example with ef4

Comment: Sorry, really haven't done anything with EF since version 1.0. But if you google a bit I'm sure you'll find a couple of examples of generic repositories for EF4.

Answer (score 3):

The Repository pattern itself is pretty explicit in those areas that require specification. The rest is left out on purpose, because it depends on my outside factors, such as your programming language, project scope and your personal programming style.

In other words: You seem to be asking for a pattern on how to apply the pattern, but in the end you will have to take your own decisions when programming.

I will try to reply to your more specific questions though:

- Yes, using Generics is a good idea for a repository. Another approach would be to have a common interface for all objects that should be stored. You might also go with both, depending on your requirements.
- Try to deal with differences in object behaviour by calling polymorphic methods on the objects to be stored.
- There should be no code repetition if you do it right (by using generics and / or interfaces).